# AWS EC2 Linux instance, after updating bindIp mongod service failing

Tags: python, mongodb, flask, amazon-ec2

I have an EC2 instance associated with ElasticBeanstalk on which my flask app is deployed. I have implemented some rest APIs using flask, python.

I created another EC2 instance on Linux 2, on which installed MongoDB community edition. I noticed that it has a local ip mapped in /etc/mongod.conf file:

```
# network interfaces
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 127.0.0.1
```

As per my understanding I need to map the private IP of EC2 instance - flask app to it:

```
# network interfaces
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: <private ip of EC2 with flask app>
```

So that I can access the MongoDB installed at this instance from the flask app.

```
# configuring mongo
application.config["MONGO_DBNAME"] = "my_db"
application.config["MONGO_URI"] = "mongodb://public_ip_of_mongodb:27017/my_app"
```

For some reasons, as soon as I edit the '/etc/mongod.conf file' mongod service starts failing:

```
mongod.service - MongoDB Database Server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2020-08-04 17:17:28 UTC; 1min 11s ago
     Docs: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual
  Process: 2019 ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod $OPTIONS (code=exited, status=48)
  Process: 2015 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/chmod 0755 /var/run/mongodb (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 2012 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/chown mongod:mongod /var/run/mongodb (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 2010 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/mkdir -p /var/run/mongodb (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 1651 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Aug 04 17:17:28 ip-172-31-5-131.ap-east-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: Starting MongoDB Database Server...
Aug 04 17:17:28 ip-172-31-5-131.ap-east-1.compute.internal mongod[2019]: about to fork child process, waiting until server is ready for connections.
Aug 04 17:17:28 ip-172-31-5-131.ap-east-1.compute.internal mongod[2019]: forked process: 2023
Aug 04 17:17:28 ip-172-31-5-131.ap-east-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: mongod.service: control process exited, code=exited status=48
Aug 04 17:17:28 ip-172-31-5-131.ap-east-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: Failed to start MongoDB Database Server.
Aug 04 17:17:28 ip-172-31-5-131.ap-east-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: Unit mongod.service entered failed state.
Aug 04 17:17:28 ip-172-31-5-131.ap-east-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: mongod.service failed.
```

Even if I revert the bindId to 127.0.0.1 it still fails.

Am I missing anything over here?

Comment: See server log. https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/log-messages/#configuring-log-message-destinations

Comment: Try setting `bindIp:` to `0.0.0.0` which is an alias for all interfaces.  This avoids having to change that conf file if/when the instance restarts and gets a newly assigned IP.

Comment: @v25 is it not a wrong practice?

Comment: @Devarshi Many apps advise using this to bind to all interface (flask for example).  There shouldn't be an issue if the instance has a single interface and the security groups are correctly configured.